# Laser Scan publisher

Tags: laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a laser scan filter based off of geometric correction. It is doing well, so I'd like to try mapping with it. After the scan is filtered, it is stored in a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud`. I need to take this and convert it to a laser scan for gmapping. Any helpful hints as to how I go about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31672/laser-scan-publisher/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [point_cloud_to_laserscan](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan).

All you need to do is publish your pcl::PointCloud use the point_cloud_to_laserscan node to get the corresponding laser scan. In the ros package turtlebot_bringup you'll find an example launch file that converts Kinect point clouds to laser scans.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-04-16**:
Ok. The topic I'm publishing is "cloud". I'm working with a topic, titled "scan" that is already running. How do I discern the two for mapping?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-04-16**:
Have a look at topic remapping: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments